# Why does Clojure not have an any? or any-pred? function?

Tags: clojure

It seems like I must be missing some obvious commonly used idiom, but the absence of these two functions seems a bit perplexing to me. There is `some` but it returns `nil` instead of `False`, why not an `any?` function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`some` is considered to be the same as `any?` would be if it existed. there is a closely named function `not-any?` which just calls `some` under the hood:

```
(source not-any?)
(def
...
not-any? (comp not some))
```

you could simply write any as:

```
(def any? (comp boolean some))
```

patches welcomed :) just fill out and mail in a contributor agreement first.

your point  about the naming is especially true considering the `not-any?` function has been included since 1.0

```
(defn any? [pred col] (not (not-any? pred col)))
(any? even? [1 2 3])
true
(any? even? [1  3])
false
```

I guess nobody got around to sending in the patch? (hint hint nudge nudge)

When using any code based on `some` (`not-any?` calls some under the hood) be careful to match the types of the pred and the col or use a pred that catches the type exceptions

```
(if (some odd? [2 2 nil 3]) 1 2)
No message.
  [Thrown class java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

ps: this example is from clojure 1.2.1

Comment: Why not just use `true?` if you really want to force the result to be Boolean? `(defn any? [pred coll] (true? (some pred coll)))`

Comment: `true?` only evaluates to true of the argument is actually the boolean value `true`.  If you want to force a value to its logical boolean value, use `boolean`.

Comment: thanks seh I edited to use your example instead, just better :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Maybe I'll consider some contributions after I feel a bit more familiar with the language.

Comment: Ah, right, Alex. I see now looking at the source that `true?` uses `identical` to test whether the argument is indeed equivalent to the value `true`. `boolean` is the better choice here.

Comment: `any?` is a core function since 1.9 that returns true no matter what.  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/any_q

Answer (score 9):

`nil` evaluates to false.  `(if nil 1 2)` evaluates to 2.

`some` returns the first element that satisfies the predicate.  Anything that is not `nil` or `false` evaluates to true.  So `(if (some odd? [2 2 3]) 1 2)` evaluates to 1.

Comment: Historical aside:  I recall something from Rich about really not wanting `false` in the language, having just nil/not-nil instead, but needing it for reasons of compatibility or utility (don't recall exactly what).

Comment: false is needed to be compatible with Java boolean types..... it makes Java interop much easier and less confusing if you treat false as false rather than considering it to be non-nil and therefore true!

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `some-fn`, although you will have to thread the return value of the predicate it generates through `boolean`.

```
user> (doc every-pred)
-------------------------
clojure.core/every-pred
([p] [p1 p2] [p1 p2 p3] [p1 p2 p3 & ps])
  Takes a set of predicates and returns a function f that returns true if all of its
  composing predicates return a logical true value against all of its arguments, else it returns
  false. Note that f is short-circuiting in that it will stop execution on the first
  argument that triggers a logical false result against the original predicates.
nil
user> (doc some-fn)
-------------------------
clojure.core/some-fn
([p] [p1 p2] [p1 p2 p3] [p1 p2 p3 & ps])
  Takes a set of predicates and returns a function f that returns the first logical true value
  returned by one of its composing predicates against any of its arguments, else it returns
  logical false. Note that f is short-circuiting in that it will stop execution on the first
  argument that triggers a logical true result against the original predicates.
nil
```

These functions are analogous in the same way that `every?` and `some` are analogous.

Answer (score 3):

These seem to be addressing "any". The question also mentioned "any-pred" How about something like this?

```
(defn any-pred [preds]
  (comp not (apply every-pred (map #(comp not %) preds))))
```

This takes a collection rather than multiple arguments, but changing that would be easy enough.

Example:

```
=> (def p (any-pred [(partial = "a") (partial = "b")]))
=> (p "a")  true
=> (p "b")  true
=> (p "c")  false
```

Comment: You can use the `some-fn`, e.g. `(def p (some-fn (partial = "a") (partial = "b")))`

Answer (score 3):

This has changed with the release of Clojure 1.9, which adds an `any?` function that returns true on any input.

The definition is simply `(defn any? [x] true)`, and the commit adding it is [0929d1](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/0929d1d13d036973a03db78a5a03f29d19c9e4b2).

---

#### **Re:** `some`, `any?`, `not-any?`, `every?`, `not-every?`

Note that this `any?` is **not** the negation of `not-any?`, like you might expect based on how `every?` and `not-every?` are implemented, but a completely new function. If you're looking for a negation (un-negation?) of `not-any?`, then the function to use is still `some`.

Comment: There was a discussion about this on the Clojure Dev mailing list, but it was shut down. This situation is just becoming ridiculous, the name choices here are pretty bad. Should be any? and not-any? and any. Or should be some? and not-some? and some. With the addition of any?, I can expect a few more objection from coworkers about Closure and not liking it due to the astonishing naming choices like that one. Not saying names matter so much once you learn them, but this is definitely counter intuitive to most anyone who learned programming with another language first.

Answer (score 0):

You can define any-pred like this :

```
(defn any-pred [& preds] (complement (apply every-pred (map complement preds))))
```

or

```
(defn any-pred [& preds] (fn [v] (boolean (some #(% v) preds))))
```